# Let $f_n:[1,2]\to[0,1]$ be given by $f_n(x)=(2-x)^n$ for all non-negative integers $n$. Let $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$ for $1\le x\le 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n:[1,2]\to[0,1]$ be given by $f_n(x)=(2-x)^n$ for all non-negative integers $n$. Let $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$ for $1\le x\le 2$. Then which of the following is true?
>
> (a) $f$ is continuous on [1,2]
>
> (b) $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^2f_n(x)dx=\int_1^2f(x)dx$
>
> (c)$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[1,2]$ as $n \to \infty$
>
> (d) for any $a\in(1,2)$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n'(a)\neq f'(a)$

Solution:

$f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)=1$ when $x=1$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x\in(1,2]$. Hence option (a), (c) are clearly incorrect.

Now for any $a\in(1,2)$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n'(a)=\lim_{n \to \infty}-n(2-a)^{n-1}=0$$ and $$f'(a)=0 \;\;\forall \;\;a\in(1,2) $$ which implies $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n'(a)= f'(a)$. Hence option (d) is incorrect as well.

Now, for part (c):

$$lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^2f_n(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=0$$ and $$\int_1^2f(x)=\int_1^20dx=0$$
Hence option (c) is correct.

Have I done everything correctly here? Also, i think $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^2f_n(x)dx=\int_1^2f(x)dx$ happens only when $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$. But here it doesn't converge uniformly then also this result holds, is there any explanation for that? Please help me in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct.

b) is true. Just evaluate the integral explicitly. $\int_1^{2} f_n(x) dx=\int_1^{2} (2-x)^{n} dx=\int_{0}^{1} y^{n} dy =\frac 1{n+1 } \to 0$. And $\int_1^{2} f(x) dx=0$.

Uniform convergence is a **sufficient** condition for the convergence of the integrals but it is not a **necessary** condition.

Comment: Yes, I added that in the edit before you posted the answer. I have a new question regarding uniform convergence, could you please answer that?

Comment: @s1mple I have added an explanation

Comment: Thank you sir ! :)